# Windows Phone Builds with different Packaging information from the same CSProj build?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, tfs, continuous-integration

I have a Windows Phone 8.0 project I want to have builds made for different environments.

Which will have different:

- Display Name
- Description
- Product Id
- Tile Title

[image]

Examples would be

- App for Live - 125-24-216906812-412196
- App for UAT - 252-62-249259125-249245
- App for CIT - 124-25-692659633-291208

The only way I can think of doing this would be to duplicate the WindowsPhone project three times, and modify the WMAppManifest.xml for each one?

This would mean code duplication which is bad, so is there a way to tell the builds on TFS to modify the Manifest file for each separate build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to have **three projects**, one original and two linking all files from the original one, with custom WMAppManifest.xml file.
Other solution I can think of is running some kind of **pre-build PowerShell script, that will modificate the WMAppManifest.xml file before building the project with fields you want**. Your build server should be able do run such script before building the solution.

Comment: Thanks, how do I link files? I tried googling but no luck.